# What is Gate time of single and multi qubit?

Tags: quantum-gate

How much quantum gate need time do computation in superconducting quantum computer. For all types of single and multi qubit gate.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking at tens to hundreds of nanoseconds. For instance Rigetti has some times for 1Q and 2Q gates here: https://qcs.rigetti.com/qpus.

You can get an idea of how to build your own custom gates with pulse schedules of this type of duration against Rigetti's Aspen-M and Oxford Quantum Circuit's Lucy with Amazon Braket on AWS in this blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/quantum-computing/amazon-braket-launches-braket-pulse-to-develop-quantum-programs-at-the-pulse-level/.